# How to open a WhatsApp chat with a pre-filled message that spans on multiple lines from my website?

Tags: php, android, html, ios, whatsapp

From [WhatsApp's FAQ section](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/28000012):

> WhatsApp provides a custom URL scheme to interact with WhatsApp:
>
> If you have a website and want to open a WhatsApp chat with a
>   pre-filled message, you can use our custom URL scheme to do so.
>   Opening whatsapp://send?text= followed by the text to send, will open
>   WhatsApp, allow the user to choose a contact, and pre-fill the input
>   field with the specified text.
>
> Here is an example of how to write this on your website:
>
> `<a href="whatsapp://send?text=Hello%20World!">Hello, world!</a>`

What if I want to have that mentioned `pre-filled message` spans on multiple lines like this:

```
Text on the first line
Text on the second line

Text on the third line
Text on the fourth line
```

I've tried to put the text in the `<a href=""></a>` tag like this:

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=First line\r\nSecond line\r\n\r\nThird line\r\nFourth line">Share on WhatsApp</a>
```

But it doesn't work, the message appears in WhatsApp like this:

```
First lineSecond lineThird lineFourth line
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP line break character `\r\n` that used within the URL in the `<a href=""></a>` tag needs to be encoded. The `urlencode()` PHP function can be used to perform this. The link must be like the following to properly open WhatsApp chat with a pre-filled message that spans on multiple lines:

```
<?php
    $msg = "First line\r\nSecond line\r\n\r\nThird line\r\nFourth line";
    $msg = str_replace("\r\n", urlencode("\r\n"), $msg); // note the double quotes

    echo "<a href='whatsapp://send?text=$msg'>Share on WhatsApp</a>";
?>
```

Now if anyone click that link while he is browsing your website from his Android or iOS device, then WhatsApp application will open to allow him to choose a contact, and pre-fill the input field with the specified text that will spans on multiple lines like this:

```
First line
Second line

Third line
Fourth line
```

Note that double quotation MUST be used i.e., `"\r\n"` NOT `'\r\n'`.

Answer (score 0):

While `urlencode($msg)` works with most mobile browsers however it encodes spaces with `+` in on firefox on android devices so your users might see text like `Text+on+the+first+line`. Better fix will be to use `rawurlencode($msg)` to keep it compatible with all browsers as it forces the text to be encoded according to RFC 3986 format.